# Read all push notification when the app isn't running

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

How to catch all remote notifications when the app is not running and i opened it from app icon not from the notifications list.

Note: Whatsapp do it

Steps i used with Whatsapp:

1- Terminate Whatsapp if running
2- Wait for 3 minutes to end background tasks if running :)
3- Send text message from another device 
4- Turn off wifi and 3g connection
5- Open Whatsapp 
6- I found the message :(

Comment: There is no way to access or "read" push notifications that are not delivered to the app delegate.  WhatsApp does not do this.  They use local notifications, which are available as a property of `UIApplication`.

Comment: Or they may just notify that there is a new message avaiable, and the app gets it from their server upon opening.

Comment: please to read the question after adding test scenarios

Comment: I think your test case is flawed. Maybe try 
1. Turn off WiFI and Cellular Data
2. Turn off device
3. Once device is turned off send a message from another device
4. Turn on device, ensure Wifi and Cellular is still off
5. Open Whatsapp

Comment: WhatsApp uses silent push notifications with background processing.  If the app is not active, it creates a local notification.  The message is either delivered as part of the silent notification, or its downloaded as part of background processing.

Comment: As i know the silent push notification not wake up the terminated apps, only apps with foreground and background states can handle notifications in didReceiveRemoteNotification.